# New Warning of Google Play Developer policy violation: Action Required?

Tags: android, permissions, google-play, policy

I want to know which one one the following permission considered sensitive and should be removed?

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`, `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION`, and `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` are all [`dangerous` permissions](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/permissions/requesting.html#normal-dangerous). As to which ones your violation might be referring to, ask Google, as [Play Store policy questions are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: Thank you but that permissions are required for showing ads

Comment: Then leave the permissions alone and deal with the policy violation in some other way. Or, remove the ads and come up with a different business model.

Comment: Can you guide me for privacy policy template and how to include it inside my apps?

Comment: You should discuss a suitable privacy policy with your attorney. In terms of how to display it, package it as HTML in `assets/` and either use `WebView` (to show it in your app) or `FileProvider` (to show it in the user's Web browser).

Comment: It's OK to ad privacy policy as a button in my first page? so if the user click that button he will go to privacy URL ?